# How do I download an app to an iPad that asks for another user's password?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, apple-id

Probably going to sound wordy to explain but I've got an issue where my Apple ID is signed into my iPad but when I try to download an app it requests my ex girlfriends password for her Apple ID. When I'm using anything else on my iPad it requests my password and it's no problem.

Does that make sense and can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

The app was downloaded / bought using your ex-girlfriend Apple ID; delete and re download the app in question.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Open the settings app and App Store - sign out of the account.
2. Then make note of all apps that need an update. You'll have to determine by which account pops up, which account bought the app in the first place.

Delete all the apps that are assigned to the account you wish to remove from the device. Sign in only with your account going forward and delete all the apps (either waiting for them to update or clearing them out more pro-actively).

Comment: This answers the asked question, however pointing out the confusion that most people don't seem to realize:  There is not one single iCloud login, in fact, there are at least 6 places in the settings app where different appleId's can be used to log in.  Check ICloud, iTunes and App Store, Messages, Facetime, Game Center and Mail Contacts and Calenders to understand which appleId is being used where.

Comment: @Tyson True - but none of the myriad places you list affect app downloading. The two places I listed are precisely the only two places AppleID can affect an app installation or update.

Comment: I agree totally and said so, you correctly answered the question that was asked.   I pointed out the others login locations because 98% of the user base doesn't realize there are multiple logins and if someone needs to make a change to one of them they may need/want to change others also.